# Code wont stop running in MIPS assembly simulation

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

```
main:
    jal addNode              # Call addNode to insert the new node
    # Assuming addNode returns the new node's value in $v0
    move $s3, $v0            # Move the returned value to $s3
    j end                    # Jump to end to halt the program

addNode:
    addi $sp, $sp, -16       # Allocate stack space for saved registers
    sw $ra, 12($sp)          # Save $ra
    sw $s0, 8($sp)           # Save head
    sw $s1, 4($sp)           # Save newNode
    sw $s2, 0($sp)           # Save n

    beq $s2, $zero, addAtStart  # If n is 0, add at the start

    # Prepare and call findNode
    move $a0, $s0            # Pass head as argument
    move $a1, $s2            # Pass n as argument
    jal findNode             # Call findNode

    # After findNode, $v0 has addr of n-th node, $v1 has addr of (n+1)-th node
    # Insert newNode after n-th node
    lw $t0, 4($v0)           # Load address of (n+1)-th node
    sw $t0, 4($s1)           # Set newNode's next to (n+1)-th node
    sw $s1, 4($v0)           # Set n-th node's next to newNode

    # Load newNode's value to return it
    lw $v0, 0($s1)           

    # Restore registers and return
    lw $s2, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 12($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16
    jr $ra

addAtStart:
    sw $s0, 4($s1)           # Set newNode's next to current head
    move $s0, $s1            # Update head to newNode
    lw $v0, 0($s1)           # Load newNode's value to return
    jr $ra                   # Return to addNode, which returns to main

findNode:
    ori $t2, $zero, 0         # Initialize loop counter to 0
    move $t0, $a0             # $t0 is the current node, start with head

    # Check if we're adding at the start (should be handled outside this function)
    beq $a1, $zero, findNode_exit  # If adding at position 0, special case

    # Iterate through the list to find the correct node
loop_findNode:
    # Check if we've reached the position before where we want to add the new node
    addi $t2, $t2, 1           # Increment counter
    beq $t2, $a1, findNode_exit # If we've reached the right position, exit loop

    lw $t0, 4($t0)             # Move to the next node
    beq $t0, $zero, findNode_exit # If next node is NULL, exit loop (end of list)

    j loop_findNode            # Jump back to start of loop

findNode_exit:
    # Prepare to return: $v0 should already have the address of the correct node
    jr $ra                     # Return to caller
                # Return to caller

end:
    j end                    # Infinite loop to halt the program
```

**i cant use syscall or nop in this simulator so i tried an infinite loop. I am getting the array values i need but the code itself wont stop running. It seems to be in a infinite loop and wont stop. When i run it through the test cases it just times out understandably **

Comment: Why not just `jr $ra`? Assuming the tester just calls your function.

Comment: An infinite loop is the *exact opposite* of halting the program...

Comment: Who/what says you can't use syscall?  The reason to ask is that perhaps that source can tell what to do instead.  I like the guess to return to caller of `main`, but `main` would need a stack frame or otherwise preserve its `$ra` value to use later to return to its caller.

Comment: @Jester i am using zybooks and apparently it doesnt exit using j $ra and instead uses j exit. if use jr $ra it will cause your program to enter an infinite loop and yield unpredictable results or time out entirely.

Comment: The most prominent reason using `jr $ra` won't work is that `$ra` is instantly wiped out by the `jal` that `main` does.  So, yes, with that value wiped out there's no possibility to return to caller, and what it *will* "return to" is the instruction after `jal` in `main`, and yes, that will make an infinite loop.  If you want to use `jr $ra`, you'll have to save & restore the incoming `$ra`, or else, don't use the `jal` instruction.  If you don't want to try that then make a very short test program `main: jr $ra` and see if that terminates properly.

Comment: This doesn't look related to the main problem, but you forgot to restore `$sp` after branching to `addAtStart`.